Distribution of one vector, subject to sample mean and sample covariance constraint.
Let $\{ X_1, \cdots, X_n \} \subset \mathbf{R}^d$ be sampled uniformly from the space of collections of $n$ points in $\mathbf{R}^d$ which satisfy
i) $\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i = 0$
ii) $\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i X_i^\top = I_d$.
Is the marginal distribution of the vector $X_1$ known? Based on some intuition from the $d = 1$ case, I would guess that it should have a density something like $p(x) \propto \left( 1 - \| x \|_2^2 \right)^{a(n, d)}$ for some $a(n, d)$, but I'm not sure how to go about proving this. Anyways, it seems like a natural enough question, so perhaps the solution is out there in the literature somewhere.

What does it exactly mean: "sampled uniformly from the space of collections"? You cannot sample uniformly from $\mathbb{R}^d$...

I think with the restrictions you can, in a certain sense... (well, of course the restrictions make it non-uniform implicitly, but still in that way you do not have to provide explicitly how you avoid the infinity problem of uniform sampling). Anyhow, OP does not say that we're samping from $\mathbf{R}^d$, but instead from the restricted "space of collections of $n$ points...", so the problem is not really present here.

PS: still I would agree that although the infinity problem of sampling from $\mathbf{R}^d$ is avoided, sampling from "the space of collections" could still be defined in different ways. So that question stands. I'd expect that effectively just using delta-functions of the constraints in the integral for computing the marginal distribution is what is intended by OP, but it should be clarified.
